# Handling design design exceptions in multi-channel designs in Altium

Tags: altium

Let's say I have a design with 5 channels. All channels are exactly the same, except the last one which has limited functionality compared to the other 4 channels and thus doesn't need some of the components.
How to handle this in Altium without creating a schematic sheet for the 4 channels and a separate copy for the 5th with just the few changes? It seems I can't place a compile mask directive in a specific channel only.

At the moment I design all 5 channels the same, place them all and route them normally on the PCB and just don't populate the components not needed on the 5th.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar conundrum, where each channel shares a pin-addressable device that uses SPI or I2C, so each address is different.

Hierarchical doesn't address minor variations. Altium can't be all things to all people; they have enough difficulty with bug control and customer service on the 1000's of features this monster has grown to be.

As such, it seems you have to decide if you want nicer layout experience, modularity, and copy room formats or flexibility and less strict net naming. Personally, I'd rather not throw out the room copy format feature over my address thing, so I am going to do what you did: stuff all the address pins with zero ohm jumpers or net ties and then create a variant where I select those parts out I don't want stuffed. I will then put a note about that in the schematic perhaps as a table. In my case, this provides some flexibility later on if I want to change this after the PCB gets made.

I suppose there might be some groovy if x=1, then do this kind of thing, but just working on that seems like a waste since I have a quick workaround here.

When Altium frustrates me (fairly often, and I've been using it since version 10), I just remind myself that this whole process used to be a paper-based drafting and photography exercise.